# Criação de um slider que não muda toda a imagem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Bom galera, pra deixar mais específio, estou buscando por algo assim:[image: estágio 1]

as setas em vermelho seriam botões, a parte em preta com as letras seria quando o  hover do mouse (o titulo "olhos" e a descrição são um link) e, quando clicasse no botão, ele deslocaria o slider, até um certo ponto para mostrar outra seção[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembrando que as seções são links (Lábios, perfeitos e bem desenhados +)

Busco uma solução por css3 ou jquery.

Comment: Considere fazer um [tour] e visitar a [help] para ver como perguntar e como não perguntar. Seja bem vindo, boa sorte. Após isso você pode [edit] sua pergunta para reabertura...

Comment: Olá, seria interessante que você colocasse o que você ja tentou fazer, e algum exemplo de seu código.